# File-oriented operation via java

Tags: java, file

I'm trying to copy the "contents" of a particular .mp4(video) file into another via the following code:

```
Path source = Paths.get("E:\\Video0001.mp4");
Path destination = Paths.get("C:\\Ritesh\\Experimentation\\GOT.mp4");  
Set<OpenOption> options = new HashSet<>();
options.add(APPEND);
options.add(CREATE);
try (SeekableByteChannel sbc = Files.newByteChannel(source);
        SeekableByteChannel sbcdes = Files.newByteChannel(destination, options)) {
    ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(10);
    String encoding = System.getProperty("source.encoding");
    while (sbc.read(buf) > 0) {
        buf.rewind();

        ByteBuffer bb =  
            ByteBuffer.wrap(((Charset.forName(encoding).decode(buf)).toString()).getBytes());
        sbcdes.write(bb);   
        buf.flip();
    }
} catch (IOException x) {
    System.out.println("caught exception: " + x);
}
```

The code executes, a destination .mp4 file is created at the desired location but the predicament is that the .mp4 file won't run....it gives me an error message, stating the input's format can't be recognized... File operations are still a novelty to me, rendering me unable to resolve this conundrum....
any form of assistance would be ecstatically appreciated! =)

Comment: Maybe I am completely misunderstanding your question, but what is wrong with a simple copy and paste? You say a destination .mp4 is created at the desired location and therefore I think you don't want to _add_ to the destination file, but just have a clone of the source file on the destination?

Comment: Are you looking for `Files.copy(source, destination)`?

Comment: i'm well aware and versed with the Files.copy method...i just wanted a closer look at the intricacies of its workings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are decoding and encoding the data (converting it to `String`s and back). This mangles anything that's not text. MP4 files aren't text.

This should work, instead of the loop you have:

```
while (sbc.read(buf) > 0) {
    buf.flip()
    sbcdes.write(buf);
    buf.clear();
}
```